# What does this pronoun "them" refer to here?

Tags: pronouns

Lately, I stumbled across a historical source text from Victorian England (Henry Mayhew, London Labour) which had following sentence:

> 'He told me, at the commencement of his statement, that he was of oppinion that his people were far more speculative than the Gentiles, and therefore the English liked better to deal with **them**.'

My question is what does the pronoun **'them'** refer to? Is it the 'Gentiles' or 'his people'?

Comment: I think it refers to "his people,' but this is indeed ambiguous.  What makes it extra difficult is that I don't know what "speculative" means in this context.  If it is a complimentary adjective, than  "them refers to "his people," but if it's pejorative, than it would be "Gentiles."

Comment: It is definitely referring to 'his people', which becomes more clear if you read the surrounding text. http://130.64.212.216/catalog/tei/tufts:UA069.005.DO.00078/chapter/c5s3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [‘It’ – ambiguous antecedent?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193357/it-ambiguous-antecedent) (essentially a duplicate, with the ambiguity concerning the antecedent of 'it' rather than 'them'. This [the duplicate] question deals with the inherent ambiguity [the antecedent not being uniquely identifiable]; the particular query here is off-topic as textual analysis [and as @We oath to creation elucidates, answerable by a little more research into the textual context].)

Comment: Thanks alot, that was very helpful!