# Possessive determiners, ambiguous references, and the question of the relevance of context

Tags: ambiguity, context, possessive-determiners

I know there are some threads and websites on the topic but unfortunately I continue to wonder about the issue of possessive determiners and ambiguous references.
Two examples:

> 1: *Sabine, the new boss of assistant project manager Mary, already demonstrating her abilities, was hired just last month.*
> 2: *Sabine, the new boss of assistant project manager Mary, already humiliating her daily, was hired just last month.*

> 3: *The new finance department of the company, already demonstrating its worth, is less than a year old.*
> 4: *The new finance department of the company, already increasing its export, is less than a year old.*

In the first example, "her" seems to refer to "Sabine" in the first sentence and to "Mary" in the second sentence. In the second example, "its" seems to refer to "The new finance department" in the first sentence and to "the company" in the second sentence.

Now, given that the context seems to indicate the intended referent, are all four constructions grammatically correct? Or is a possessive determiner with a multitude of potential referents always a grammatical error?

Comment: I'd say this answers the question about ambiguity due to indeterminate pronoun antecedents (grammatically acceptable, but if not resolved by context, unacceptable on the grounds of a Gricean maxim {4}  violation). [‘It’ – ambiguous antecedent?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193357/it-ambiguous-antecedent)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are grammatically correct. The antecedent of a pronoun can often only be determined from context. To adapt [an example from Wikipedia:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_linguistic_example_sentences)

1. The large ball crashed right through the table because it was made of Styrofoam.
2. The large ball crashed right through the table because it was made of steel.

Clearly "it" refers to the table in (1) and the ball in (2), something that can only be inferred from one's knowledge of the properties of steel and Styrofoam.

Comment: @Tuffy In OP's examples, what's ambiguous is not which noun is being modified by the participle, but rather which noun is the antecedent of a pronoun within the participial phrase.

Comment: @ alphabet - Oops, I was careless.  I'll put it right, thank you.