To which object in a previous sentence does "those" refer?
For example, in the sentence:

The cats rarely have fleas. Those that are there are orange.

Those is intended to refer to the fleas, but is that incorrect? Can those only refer to the cats?

Assume the last noun. If not, then the most recent logical reference. See The Wizard of Oz, "You mean she bit you?" "No, her dog!" "Oh, she bit her dog?"

@YosefBaskin Which may require knowledge the reader doesn't have. E.g. I know there are orange (e.g. calico) cats, I didn't know there were orange fleas.

Yes, it can. Consider Our granddaughters eat lots of “grown-up” foods. Those include anchovies and blue cheese.

It can, of course. It remains the writer’s responsibility to write clearly.

IMO the second sentence is clear. It would need to be "Those that do [have fleas] are orange" for it to refer to the cats' colour, but as written the fleas are orange. An ambiguity would be "The cats rarely have fleas. They are orange."

The second half is confusing because it's hard to figure out the structure or parse: there's the repetition of "are", and too many similar words like all the "th-" words, plus "there are orange" feels like a clause but isn't. This is a bigger problem than working out the referent, IMO.

Is your question about that specific sentence, or are you asking for a rule that applies to all sentences?

If the latter, my answer here may be relevant: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/609784/

The antecedent of "those" is ambiguous — it could be the cats, or it could be the fleas — so this is not good writing, despite its being grammatical.

No, those does not refer to the cats. If you want it to refer to the cats: The cats rarely have fleas. Those that do are orange.

A: I hear you have cats and dogs available. I am looking for an orange pet, but I don't want one with fleas. B: The cats rarely have fleas. Those that are there (pointing to a particular enclosure) are orange. Contrived, I know. But it is important to know what there refers to. Without more context it means on the cats, so it would be the fleas.

It would be a violation of Grice's maxim of manner (submaxim clarity) if one wrote this with 'cats' the intended antecedent. The change of focus would be unnaturally abrupt. But the whole sounds clumsy. Re-ordering is probably better, fronting the more intrinsic attribute: 'The cats living there are all orange. They rarely have fleas.'

This English language wasn't ready for prime time. Yet another example of the pressure to be first to market.

{Those that are there} refers to fleas.
Those that are there = those that are present.
Were it the cats that were orange the sentence would be
The cats rarely have fleas. Those that have [fleas] are orange.
